# Need to pull arithmetic and logical operator from database using Java Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new on JavaScript and working on one scenario where I am pulling the values from database using text auto-complete menu in JavaScript. I am able to pull string values from database but not able to pull arithmetic and logical operator from database.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var obj = [];
    @{
        foreach(var item in Model.WholeList)
        { 

            @:obj.push('@item.Value');
        }
    }
    $('#mytext').textcomplete([{
        words: obj,
        match: /\b(\w{1,})$/,
        search: function (term, callback) {
            callback($.map(this.words, function (word) {
                return word.search(new RegExp(term,"i")) == 0 ? word : null;
            }));
        },
        index: 1,
        replace: function (word) {
            return word + ' ';
        }
    }]);      
});
```

Please help me how to pull operator using auto-complete menu.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think the jquery plugin you are using is only allowing you to fetch the text value from the database , try `.autocomplete()` jQuery method.

[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote)